# TypeError Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

I'm facing this error when I add ForeignKeys in my Order table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYSAz.png)

Here are my tables

```
from itertools import product
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    emails = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = 
    True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
        ('Out Door', 'Out Door'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    price = models.FloatField(null = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, choices = 
    CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank 
    = True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = 
    True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('pending', 'pending'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null = True, on_delete = 
    models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null = True, on_delete = 
    models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = 
    True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, choices = 
    STATUS)
```

But when I remove the those ForeignKeys it works fine without giving an error...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5n81.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhndX.png)

...But I also can't access other tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wiAp.png)

Comment: Hey, thank you for advising me to type code. I edited my comments can you please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code (The `def __str__` that returns from the Orders Class). But it seems to me that **you're trying to return an Object as a string.**

***ie***: You want to show the `__str__` property of a created object as your Foreign Key Product "Whole Object".

But you can't return the object 'Product' as as string. Think that that's what you're doing when you do this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.product  # <-- This is an the object, not a string or the __str__ property
```

You'll be returning the object address in the memory, and since that object doesn't exist yet, it's returning None.

Try to cast your return as a explicit string

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.product) # <-- Returns the __str__ of the FK Object.
```

or try to return on atribute that's already a string

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name # <-- Returns the attribute from the FK Object.
```

Comment: But I'm basically trying to show/ inherit customer names from customers table and product names from product table.

Comment: I want the Order table to access those name from other tables.